# What is the integral of powers of sines and cosines over one period?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am looking for an expression for the integral
\begin{equation*}
I_{n,m}=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n(x)\sin^m(x) \, dx
\end{equation*}
where $n,m$ are arbitrary positive integers. Thanks

Comment: by substituting $u=x/4$ then simplifying trig identies then apply Beta function.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: The simplest approach (to me) might be to use complex exponentials.

Comment: Isn't the Beta function defined using limits of integration 0 to $\pi/2$ and only for $n,m$ odd?

Comment: Yse, you are right. Thanks

Comment: You should try to come up with a reduction formula via integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

The problem is how to reduce the cosine and sine with degrees to cosine and sine of multiple arguments, since $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(mx)$ are orthogonal on the interval $(0,2\pi):$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(nx)\sin(mx)=0,$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(nx)\cos(mx)=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)=
\begin{cases}
2\pi\text{ for }n=m=1\\
\pi\text{ for }n=m\not=1\\
0\text{ for }n\not=m.
\end{cases}$$

To reduce, it's possible to use the formula
$$2\cos(nx)=z^n+\bar z^n,\quad 2i\sin(mx)=z^m-\bar z^m,\quad z=e^{ix},\quad \bar z=e^{-ix},$$
then 
$$2^n\cos^n(x)=(z+\bar z)^n = \sum_{k=0}^h
\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{n}{k}\left(z^{n-2k}+\bar z^{n-2k}\right)+(n-2h-1)\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{n}{h}$$
$$=2\sum_{k=0}^h
\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{n}{k}\cos(n-2k)x + (n-2h-1)\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{n}{h},$$
where $h=\left[\dfrac{n}2\right]$;
$$(2i)^m\sin^m(x)=(z-\bar z)^n$$
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^{h'}(-1)^k\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{m}{k}\left(z^{m-2k}+(-1)^m\bar z^{m-2k}\right) + (-1)^{h'}(m-2h'-1)\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{n}{h'}$$
$$=
\begin{cases}
2\sum_{k=0}^l(-1)^k\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{m}{k}\cos(m-2k)x + (-1)^l\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{n}{l}\text{ for }m=2l\\
2i\sum_{k=0}^l(-1)^k\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{}{m}{k}\sin(m-2k)x\text{ for }m=2l+1
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an expansion on Cameron Williams' comment.

First, it's easy to see that if either $m$ or $n$ is odd, then the integral is zero. Thus, let's try to evaluate
$$a_{m,n}=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}(x)\sin^{2m}(x)\,dx.$$

Second, we expect symmetry in the result, i.e. $a_{m,n}=a_{n,m}$. So we can assume WLOG that $m<n$.

Now, using the facts that
$$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} \: \text{ and } \: \sin(x) = i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2},$$
together with the binomial expansion and the fact that 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{kit}\,dt=0$$
for any integer $k$, we get
\begin{align}
  \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}(x)\sin^{2m}(x)\,dx &= \int_0^{2\pi} 
     \frac{1}{2^{2n}}(e^{it}+e^{-it})^{2n}
     \frac{(-1)^m}{2^{2m}}(e^{it}-e^{-it})^{2m} \,dt \\
 &= \frac{(-1)^m}{4^{m+n}}\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2m}
     \left(\begin{array}{c}2n\\j\end{array}\right)e^{(2n-2j)it}
     \left(\begin{array}{c}2m\\k\end{array}\right)(-1)^k e^{(2m-2k)it} \, dt \\
 &= \frac{(-1)^m}{4^{m+n}}\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{j+k=m+n}
    (-1)^k\left(\begin{array}{c}2n\\j\end{array}\right)
     \left(\begin{array}{c}2m\\k\end{array}\right) 
     e^{(2((m+n)-(k+j))it} \, dt \\
  &= 2\pi\frac{(-1)^m}{4^{m+n}} \sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k 
      \left(\begin{array}{c}2m\\k\end{array}\right)
      \left(\begin{array}{c}2n\\m+n-k\end{array}\right).
\end{align}
Note that the reduction in the next to last line making the sum over only those $k$ and $j$ such that $k+j=m+n$ arises because that forces the argument of the exponential to be zero. We can ignore those $k$ and $j$ that *don't* satisfy that condition because the resulting integral will be zero. That allows us to express $j$ in terms of $k$ and condense the sum to one index variable at the next step. Of course, the resulting integrals that remain are all just $2\pi$.

I would not be at all surprised if that formula can be simplified using some binomial identities. In fact, Felix Martin shows that the integral can be expressed in terms of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), which is directly related to the binomial coefficients. The formula given here is certainly sufficient for computation. Using it, we get the following values for $0\leq 2m,2n\leq 16$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 2 \pi  & \pi  & \frac{3 \pi }{4} & \frac{5 \pi }{8} &
   \frac{35 \pi }{64} & \frac{63 \pi }{128} & \frac{231 \pi
   }{512} & \frac{429 \pi }{1024} & \frac{6435 \pi }{16384}
   \\
 \pi  & \frac{\pi }{4} & \frac{\pi }{8} & \frac{5 \pi }{64}
   & \frac{7 \pi }{128} & \frac{21 \pi }{512} & \frac{33 \pi
   }{1024} & \frac{429 \pi }{16384} & \frac{715 \pi }{32768}
   \\
 \frac{3 \pi }{4} & \frac{\pi }{8} & \frac{3 \pi }{64} &
   \frac{3 \pi }{128} & \frac{7 \pi }{512} & \frac{9 \pi
   }{1024} & \frac{99 \pi }{16384} & \frac{143 \pi }{32768}
   & \frac{429 \pi }{131072} \\
 \frac{5 \pi }{8} & \frac{5 \pi }{64} & \frac{3 \pi }{128} &
   \frac{5 \pi }{512} & \frac{5 \pi }{1024} & \frac{45 \pi
   }{16384} & \frac{55 \pi }{32768} & \frac{143 \pi
   }{131072} & \frac{195 \pi }{262144} \\
 \frac{35 \pi }{64} & \frac{7 \pi }{128} & \frac{7 \pi
   }{512} & \frac{5 \pi }{1024} & \frac{35 \pi }{16384} &
   \frac{35 \pi }{32768} & \frac{77 \pi }{131072} & \frac{91
   \pi }{262144} & \frac{455 \pi }{2097152} \\
 \frac{63 \pi }{128} & \frac{21 \pi }{512} & \frac{9 \pi
   }{1024} & \frac{45 \pi }{16384} & \frac{35 \pi }{32768} &
   \frac{63 \pi }{131072} & \frac{63 \pi }{262144} &
   \frac{273 \pi }{2097152} & \frac{315 \pi }{4194304} \\
 \frac{231 \pi }{512} & \frac{33 \pi }{1024} & \frac{99 \pi
   }{16384} & \frac{55 \pi }{32768} & \frac{77 \pi }{131072}
   & \frac{63 \pi }{262144} & \frac{231 \pi }{2097152} &
   \frac{231 \pi }{4194304} & \frac{495 \pi }{16777216} \\
 \frac{429 \pi }{1024} & \frac{429 \pi }{16384} & \frac{143
   \pi }{32768} & \frac{143 \pi }{131072} & \frac{91 \pi
   }{262144} & \frac{273 \pi }{2097152} & \frac{231 \pi
   }{4194304} & \frac{429 \pi }{16777216} & \frac{429 \pi
   }{33554432} \\
 \frac{6435 \pi }{16384} & \frac{715 \pi }{32768} &
   \frac{429 \pi }{131072} & \frac{195 \pi }{262144} &
   \frac{455 \pi }{2097152} & \frac{315 \pi }{4194304} &
   \frac{495 \pi }{16777216} & \frac{429 \pi }{33554432} &
   \frac{6435 \pi }{1073741824} \\
\end{array}
$$

Of course, you can use a good computer algebra system to check that this much is correct at least.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I_{nm} & \equiv \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\sin^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\pars{-1}^{m + n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\sin^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{m + n}\,\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}^{m}}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\sin^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\pars{-1}^{m + n} + \pars{-1}^{n}}\bracks{
\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\pars{x}\cos^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\pars{-1}^{m} + 1}\braces{\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}^{n}}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\pars{x}\cos^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\pars{-1}^{m} + 1}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{n} + 1}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\pars{x}\cos^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$$
\fbox{$\ds{\quad I_{nm} = \bracks{\pars{-1}^{m} + 1}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{n} + 1}I_{mn}\quad}$}
$$

---

With $\ds{t \equiv \sin\pars{x}}$, the last integral in \eqref{1} is given by:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\pars{x}\cos^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{m/2 - 1/2}\,\,\,\dd t =
\half\int_{0}^{1}t^{n/2 - 1/2}\,\,\,\pars{1 - t}^{m/2 - 1/2}\,\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\half\,
{\Gamma\pars{n/2 + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{m/2 + 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n/2 + m/2 + 1}}
\end{align}
where we used the *Beta Function* expression in terms of the *Gamma Function* $\ds{\Gamma}$.

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I_{nm}} & \equiv \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{n}\pars{x}\sin^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\color{#f00}{\half\bracks{\pars{-1}^{m} + 1}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{n} + 1}
{\Gamma\pars{n/2 + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{m/2 + 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n/2 + m/2 + 1}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

These are dealt with in pretty much any Calculus text.
  If either sine or cosine is to an **odd** power, a simple substitution reduces it to an algebraic integral:

1) $\int \sin^n(x)\cos^{2k+1}(x)\, dx= \int \sin^n(x) \cos^{2k}(x) (\cos(x)\,dx)$
  Let $u= \sin(x)$ so that $du= \cos(x)\,dx$, $\cos^2(x)= 1- \sin^2(x)= 1- u^2$ and $\cos^{2k}(x)= (1- u^2)^k$.  The integral becomes $\int u^n(1- u^2)^k \,du$.

2) $\int \sin^{2k+ 1}(x)\cos^m(x)\,dx= \int \sin^{2k}(x)\cos^m(x)(\sin(x) \, dx)$
  Let $u= cos(x)$ so that $du= -\sin(x)\,dx$, $\sin^2(x)= 1- \cos^2(x)= 1- u^2$, and $\sin^{2k}(x)= (1- u^2)^k$.  The integral becomes $\int (1- u^2)^ku^m \,du$.

If both sine and cosine are to an even power use $\sin^2(x)= (1- \cos(2x))/2$ and $\cos^2(x)= (1+ \cos(2x))/2$, repeatedly if necessary, to reduce to a form in which either sine or cosine has an odd power.